# Using Mod in an Abstract Syntax Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I am having trouble with the Mod operator in Haskell Its inferring the wrong  type based on what I have. Mod is at the bottom of eval. I am new to Haskell and am making an AST with expr for class. Here is the code I have so far. I am sure its a simple fix but cant seem to get it.

```
data Expr = Add Expr Expr
      | Sub Expr Expr
      | Mult Expr Expr
      | EqualTo Expr Expr
      | GreaterThan Expr Expr
      | LessThan Expr Expr
      | Mod Expr
      | NotEqual Expr Expr

      | Const Integer
      | VarName String
      | TrueE
      | FalseE
  deriving (Show,Eq) 


eval :: Expr -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
eval (Add e1 e2) env = eval e1 env + eval e2 env
eval (Sub e1 e2) env = eval e1 env - eval e2 env
eval (Mult e1 e2) env = eval e1 env * eval e2 env
eval (EqualTo e1 e2) env | eval e1 env == eval e2 env = 1
                     | otherwise = 0 
eval (GreaterThan e1 e2) env | eval e1 env > eval e2 env = 1
             | otherwise = 0    
eval (LessThan e1 e2) env | eval e1 env < eval e2 env = 1
          | otherwise = 0
eval (NotEqual e1 e2) env | eval e1 env /= eval e2 env = 1
                      | otherwise = 0
eval (Mod e1) env =  mod eval e1 env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are building an evaluator for AST, which represents a mathematical expression.

Haskell function [mod](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amod) receives two arguments, but your AST receives only one argument, and function `mod` in your evaluator receives three arguments. Try to change the function `eval` and data `Expr` like this

```
data Expr =
   | Mod Expr Expr

eval :: Expr -> [(String, Integer)] -> Integer
eval (Mod e1 e2) env = mod (eval e1 env) (eval e2 env)
```

In the above code, function `mod` receives two arguments, `eval e1 env` and `eval e2 env` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong notation for mod it should be

```
eval e1 env `mod` eval e2 env
```

Stupid mistake.. mod should be surrounded by back ticks.